# Meta tags are not updating in my angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.3
Node: 8.11.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.4
... common, core, forms, http, language-service
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.7
@angular-devkit/core               7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.2.4
@angular/animations                7.2.14
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.3
@angular/compiler                  7.2.11
@angular/compiler-cli              7.2.9
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                  7.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.1
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.7
@schematics/angular                7.3.3
@schematics/update                 0.13.3
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.29.0
```

I know angular is a SPA (Single Page Application ) and required SSR ( Server Side Rendering ) for updating the meta tags .. i tried `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal` but i got an empty error and it doesnt create or update files..

```
ERROR: 
ERROR: If you think that this error shouldn't occur, please fill up bug report here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/new
```

Here is how I'm updating meta tags

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor( 
  private meta: Meta
) { }
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: desc })
```

**Note** In my inspect element i can see my meta tags updating but not in view source

Any other solution will be appreciated!

Comment: Check console server side for errors when running universal

Comment: @David thanx for the response .. but  it doesnt create or update files to ran the universal

Comment: When angular universal does not work, it's usually because a server side errors stops the rendering.